# How can I access the current application folder in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to access a subfolder in the application folder whose path is:

> C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App2\App2\Templates

and retrieves all the data inside. I need to read the xml files in a subfolder of it, parse them, and store them in a dictionary. I have the parsers ready but just don't know how I can access the folder?

I tried

```
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFolder templateFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("Templates");
```

But it didn't work. An error occurred indicating that folder "Templates" could not be found. However, when I tried "Assets" instead, which had been in the folder ever since the project was created, it worked. How can I access it?

Comment: InstalledLocation is *read-only* - you cannot create files/folders there. If you want to save some data inside the app, then use *LocalFolder*.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I just need to read all the StorageFiles in a certain folder?

Comment: It depends on folder. Are you trying to access files that are delivered with your app (content) or create/download files later on?

Comment: If you want to know it, you should post another question about reading all files in certain folder))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225959/how-to-enable-documentslibrary-capability-in-a-windows-store-winrt-app

Comment: @Romasz I am needing to access the files in a subfolder.

Comment: Is this subfolder provided with your app (is it set as content)? Also - do you have any file in that folder that is set to *Content*?

Comment: Is it in your project?

Comment: Describe "it didn't work". Because the code looks sort of OK. I think @Romasz means: are the files actually there?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just editted the question! Yes the folder is there. What I was trying to do is first access the templates folder and then access the files. But the folder appears to be invisible from the codes.

Comment: I solved it... I just didn't have the folder in my Solution Explorer. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

If `Template` folder is in your project, then you can get it via:

```
var TempFile = "ms-appx:///Templates/Yourfile.jpg";
```

Comment: The answer you have provided is just a string. If you mean to access a file by application uri, then yes - it's possible, but it should also work with InstalledLocation. It also seems that OP wants to parse the folder rather than to get a single file.