# Where is documentLibrary capability in VS2017?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 Community 15.3.5, for UWP application where is the option of `documentLibrary` capability in package app manifest?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable DocumentsLibrary capability in a Windows store (WinRT) app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225959/how-to-enable-documentslibrary-capability-in-a-windows-store-winrt-app)